# SQL - to lock or not to lock: selecting next unused code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Please provide some advice to the following problem:
I have a list of unique codes. The code must be used only once, so there is a status associated with each code ( used / not-used ).

I am worried about contention / race conditions, if multiple threads will try to get next unused code.

What's best way to implement it using SQL database ( MySQL in my case )?

**The first option** is to use locking and read-committed isolation level:

```
start transaction in read-committed isolation level
select code from code_table where status = 'not-used' for update
update code_table set status = 'used' where code = :code
commit transaction
```

In the case of contention of the threads, I believe that "database threads" will stumble on the locked row, will wait unless the row write lock will be released, will see ( because of read-committed isolation level ) that this code record is already used and move on to other code records.

**The second option** is to use something similar to hibernate optimistic locking ( we don't use hibernate ), here is the description of the steps:

```
start transaction in default isolation level ( read-repeatable )
select code from code_table where status = 'not-used'
commit transaction

start transaction in default isolation level ( read-repeatable )
update code_table set status = 'used' where code = :code
commit transaction
```

In Java code I will check how much records were updated. If there is one record updated everything is ok, if there is 0 records updated - I repeat the step..after 3rd ( or 5th ) trial - throw an exception.

Any help/advice would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance

Comment: Ok, removed sql-server....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option - optimistic locking - seems to be a pretty bad idea.
From WIkipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control

> **Optimistic concurrency control (OCC)** . . . . . . .
>   . . . . . . . . is generally used in
>   **environments with low data contention**. When conflicts are rare,
>   transactions can complete without the expense of managing locks and
>   without having transactions wait for other transactions' locks to
>   clear, leading to higher throughput than other concurrency control
>   methods. However, **if contention for data resources is frequent, the
>   cost of repeatedly restarting transactions hurts performance
>   significantly**; it is commonly thought that other concurrency control
>   methods have better performance under these conditions. However,
>   locking-based ("pessimistic") methods also can deliver poor
>   performance because locking can drastically limit effective
>   concurrency even when deadlocks are avoided.

I can easily imagine the following scenario with X concurrent threads:

- thread #1 gets a next unused record **#1**
- thread #2 gets a next unused record **#1**
- thread #3 gets a next unused record **#1**
- thread #4 gets a next unused record **#1** 

  .....

  .....
- thread #1 updates the record #1, then takes next available record **#2**
- thread #2 **detects a collision** while trying to update the record #1, so **retries** and takes next available record **#2**
- thread #3 **detects a collision** while trying to update the record #1, so **retries** and takes next available record **#2**
- thread #4 **detects a collision** while trying to update the record #1, so **retries** and takes next available record **#2**
  .....
  .....
  .....
  and so on, and so on. Lots of conflicts and retries.

---

You have to stick to the first option. 
To reduce contention, you may want to keep transactions as short as possible.

Comment: thank you! we implemented the first option, but it's good to have someone confirmed.